# How can i get the fields of an index from elastic search?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I have JSON object returned from elastic search like below, I am able to get the data using this,

```
  $scope.results = response.hits.hits;
     console.log($scope.results);
     var resultstofilter = [];
     var resultArray = [];
     for (var i=0; i<$scope.results.length; ++i) {
      var result = $scope.results[i];
      resultstofilter[i] = {};
      for (var key in result) {
      if (key === '_source' || key === 'Calls') {
           var Oriobj = result[key];
           resultArray.push(Oriobj);
           console.log(resultArray);
           $scope.resultData =  resultArray;


         }
       }
     }
     for(var key in $scope.resultData) {

      }
});
```

**Result:**

[image]
I need to get the fields of an index. Say in this sample.

```
Agent
Calls
```

Is there a way i can directly get the value of key like we do in c#.Something like this,

```
$scope.resultData["key"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. One of them is to use `underscore` `_.pluck`

```
var getIndex = _.pluck($scope.resultData,'_index');
```

**Or:**

```
$scope.resultData.filter(function(myObject) {
    for (var prop in myObject) {
        if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            $scope.fieldsOfIndex.push(prop);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: is this only for elastic search or we can use anywhere in javascript?

Comment: i actually dont get this codewhy you are hardcoding 'index'?

Comment: I don't understand what you said..  I will suggest you go for the first part of answer and you will get your answer.

Comment: ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Comment: You need to add Underscore to use _.pluck. UnderscoreJS is a javascript library..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69441/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-ved).